# How to create the uplifter sound effect in some Kawaii Future Bass music?

Tags: sound-design, electronic-music

Some Examples:

0:50~1:00

0:30~0:37

How can I create it with basic synthesizers and filters.

Comment: Hi Alex, first start playing with sweep oscillators or sweep filters. That will give you a start point in terms of knowing what to search for. I think we have a number of questions on here on this topic so please have a look round.